# JSXGraphm with MathJax in fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, mathjax, jsxgraph

I have this small piece of JSXgraph code:

```
JXG.Options.text.useMathJax = true; // <-- 
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('BOX-test', { showFullscreen: true });
var point=board.create('point', [0,0]);
```

When I go in fullscreen mode, all good, but I have the following problem as soon
as I try to drag something, like move the point: the
board immediately goes back to its normal size, and stays on top of a weird
gray page (I don't see my webpage anymore), like so:
[Gray page on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOADy.png).

But as soon as I remove the first line `JXG.Options.text.useMathJax = true;`,
the problem dissapears and I can drag the point in fullscreen mode.

This means that if the board contains some LaTeX, I can't really interact with
the elements (points, sliders, etc.) when in fullscreen.

Note: I have observed this phenomenon on Firefox and Chrome, so the
problem is apparently not related to the browser.

Comment: This seems to result from a very specific combination of some components. Could you please post your specific example either on jsfiddle or by mail, or as ticket at https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph?

Comment: Just for the record: a solution has been pushed to the 1.2.3 branch at github. Thanks a lot for your help.